# What is the DB2 equivalent of DUMP function in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, db2, dump

The [dump function in Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dump.php) displays the character set and bitwise representation of how data is stored.

Does anybody know if there is an equivalent command in DB2 please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following query and the functions below up might be able to come up with a UDF to do what you need.

```
    SELECT NAME, VALUE
    FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG
    where NAME in ('codepage','codeset','collate_info')

    BITAND
    BITOR
    BITXOR
    BITNOT
    BITANDNOT
```